# SegmentedControl hide and show TableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm working on an exercise application where the user is able to do use a UISwitch to set if a exercise is active or not. I have a segmented controller that is used to switch to show "All" or only to show "Active".

Is it possible to get the specific cells with this property within my UISegmentedControl Action?

My code looks like this:

```
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChallengeCell") as? ChallengeListCell {
        cell.setTitle("Utmaning " + String(indexPath.row + 1))
        let active = indexPath.row % 3 == 0 || indexPath.row % 5 == 0
        cell.setActive(active)
        if active {
            cell.setCompleted((Double(indexPath.row % 5) + Double(indexPath.row % 3)) / 6.0)
        }
        else {
            cell.setCompleted(0)
        }
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

and my SegmentedControl function looks like this:

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    let selectedSegment = segmentedControl!.selectedSegmentIndex
    switch selectedSegment{
    case 0: //SHOW ALL
        print("Selected 0")
    case 1:  //SHOW ONLY ACTIVE
        print("Selected 1")
    //case 2: //NOT ACTIVE
        //print("Selected 2")
    default:
        print(sender)
    }
}
```

All of this is in the same Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have three datasource arrays: for example `allItems` `activeItems` and `inactiveItems`, and switch between them.

Inside the `tableView` delegates check the segment selected with the segmentedControl and use the right array as datasource.

Inside `segmentedControlChanged` call `self.tableView.reloadData()` and set a variable with the selected segment.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to keep track of the index paths of "Active" cells in an array that's an instance property of your view controller. Than when the segmented controller is toggled, you can determine what cells to remove/add from the table view just by looking at the array.

Another idea would be to have an active property on the model objects that hold the data for each table view cell. When the segmented control is toggled, you can iterate over all of these objects to determine if they're "Active" or not and proceed accordingly.

From your code provided, it sounds like my first suggestion would be most appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll check this out!